# Symfony2 : Doctrine "could not find driver"

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine

Two days ago, I started coding a webapp with Symfony. For now, I'm trying to use Doctrine to save a new User (I already created an Entity and the 'linked' table in my database with the command `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`).

When i'm using a POST HTTP request on my subscribe form, Symfony tells me :

> could not find driver
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

I found a lot of solution on Google and here, but none of them worked :/

The command `php -m` gives me :

> ...
>
> PDO
>
> pdo_mysql
>
> ...

I don't undestand why this isn't working, because Doctrine could generate the User Entity and connect to the mysql database (since it created a table named 'User' in it).

phpinfo() tells me that "PDO drivers" has "no value". I guess that's why I have some my problem.

Also, it tells me :

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path :   /etc/php5/cli
>
> Loaded Configuration File : /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

I added the following lines in the file "/etc/php5/cli/php.ini" and restarted the apache server with the "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" command, but it changed nothing =/

> extension=php_mysql.so
>
> extension=php_mysqli.so
>
> extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
>
> extension=pdo.so

"php --ini" now yields :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
>
> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini

Where are supposed to be located the pdo drivers ? I guess I'm missing something ?

Comment: Make sure the extension is registered in php.ini used with your web server as well as in command line. There might be a different php.ini configuration file for command line and apache/php-fpm/cgi.

Comment: Make a simple info.php with <?php phpinfo(); ?> and browse to it.  That will help your confirm what @JakubZalas suggested.

Comment: What does the command line "php --ini" yield?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet? If so, I'd love to know because I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue is caused by not having pdo enabled for webserver's PHP. PHP can have different configurations for CLI and webserver. All your output comes from the PHP CLI. But your CLI's `php.ini` is fine, that's why the console is working. It's the CGI or FPM that's not set up properly.

You need to locate CGI or FPM `php.ini` (location may change depending on your setup - refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file) for more info) and make sure that PDO and PDO driver you want to use is enabled there.